# rvm default still not working

Tags: ruby, rvm

This is such a pain. It's happened before but still unable to figure it out.

```
[~]$ rvm use 2.1.5
Using /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
[~]$ rvm get head
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
No GPG software exists to validate rvm-installer, skipping.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/snowcrash/.mkshrc /Users/snowcrash/.profile /Users/snowcrash/.bashrc /Users/snowcrash/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/snowcrash/.profile /Users/snowcrash/.bash_profile /Users/snowcrash/.zlogin.
    Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsetsError running 'command gem install /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/log/1434304025_ruby-2.0.0-p195/gem.install.rvm->=1.11.3.9.log
[2015-06-14 13:47:05] command
current path: /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/src/rvm
GEM_HOME=/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global
PATH=/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/Users/snowcrash/Library/ec2-api-tools-1.3-24159/bin:/Users/snowcrash/bin:/Users/snowcrash/Library/android-sdk-mac_86:/Users/snowcrash/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools:/Users/snowcrash/Library/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/snowcrash/bin/gsutil:/usr/local/graphviz-2.14/bin 
GEM_PATH=/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global
```

I've checked .bash_profile files, etc but all seem to use 2.1.5. Where is 2.0.0 coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message states "No GPG software exists". You will need to install grpg2 first.  You can do that with brew:

```
brew install gpg2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default, then you need to do

`rvm --default use 2.1.5`

then `ruby -v` should have the correct version.

[Source](https://rvm.io/rubies/default)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code

```
rvm use 2.1.5 --default
```

You should see

```
Using ... /ruby-2.1.5
```

Or you can check by typing `ruby -v`